# PHP receive JSON object from Android studio volley Get request

Tags: php, json, android-volley, jsondecoder

I am using Android studio to send a GET request using volley. I am including a HashMAP parameter (called whereArray). My URL request from the volley request looks like this...

`https://xxxxxxxx.co.za/api/select_from_fact_sighting.php?whereArray={country_name=Botswana, region=Southern Africa}`

I need assistance working with this parameter on the server side - where I want to loop through it and implode it into a sql where clause. But I'm battling to decode the array in my php script (I'm assuming it should be converted to a Json object?). I've included a snippet from the php function where I try to decode the array.

````
public function select_from_fact_sighting($whereArray) {

    $jsonArray = json_decode($whereArray);
    $elementCount  = count($jsonArray); ```
````

The value in the $whereArray is `{country_name=Botswana, region=Southern Africa}`
But the value in $jsonArray is empty and $elementCount is 0 implying there is nothing in the json decoded array. Any assistance in decoding the parameter in PHP and looping through the resultant array would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: wasn't volley deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{country_name=Botswana, region=Southern Africa}` is not a valid JSON, it should be `{"country_name": "Botswana", "region": "Southern Africa"}`

Additionnaly, `json_decode()` returns an object per default, not an array, if you want an array, you need to pass `true` as second parameter : `json_decode($whereArray, true)`

See documentation : [PHP json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)